# current userid not matching in report

Tags: apex, dashboard, custom-report-type, custom-reports

Hi I have to fetch current users created records in a report. For that I have a field userid__c in a custom object which is storing user SF id (18 digit) and when I am checking userid__c=$user.id it is always returning false but when i am changing the 18 digit to 15 digit id then it is returning true.
How can i fix this?

Comment: Does [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/118781/evaluate-current-user-for-flow-15-18-digit-user-id) help?

Answer (score 0):

If userid__c is a text field, then Salesforce will only know to compare against the actual text stored in that field, if you change it to a lookup field, it should compare against both the 15 and 18 digit Id.